# FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string

I'm running below code to clean text

```
import pandas as pd

def not_regex(pattern):
        return r"((?!{}).)".format(pattern)
    
tmp = pd.DataFrame(['No one has a European accent either @',
                    'That the kid   reminds me of Kevin'])

tmp[0].str.replace(not_regex('(\\b[-/]\\b|[a-zA-Z0-9])'), ' ')
```

Then it returns a warning

```
<ipython-input-8-ef8a43f91dbd>:9: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
  tmp[0].str.replace(not_regex('(\\b[-/]\\b|[a-zA-Z0-9])'), ' ')
```

Could you please elaborate on the reason of this warning?

Comment: In `Series.str.replace` the the current default value for the param `regex` is set to True. In a future version it will be defaulted to false: `regex=False` This means in the future, if you want to use regex with str,replace you will need to set the regex param to True. [str.replace docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace). You can also look at the depreciation list [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecationse)

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing to note: "In addition, single character regular expressions will not be treated as literal strings when regex=True is set"

Answer (score 127, accepted):

See [Pandas 1.2.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecationse):

> The default value of *regex* for [`Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) will change from *True* to *False* in a future release. In addition, single character regular expressions will not be treated as literal strings when *regex=True* is set ([GH24804](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24804))

I.e., use regular expressions explicitly now:

```py
dframe['colname'] = dframe['colname'].str.replace(r'\D+', regex=True)
```

Comment: does it means that if you don't use regex you shouldn't mind about this warning ?

Comment: if you specify `string.str.replace("nan", "", regex=False)` (or whatever your use case is), you will not get the warning.

Comment: @lcrmorin If you do not use regex, be aware the old library will treat it as a regex. ALWAYS specify if you are using or not using a regex, it is safest.

Answer (score 4):

I have like

```
df.Experience.head(5)
```

```
0    24 years experience
1    12 years experience
2     9 years experience
3    12 years experience
4    20 years experience
Name: Experience, dtype: object
```

I use like

```
df['Experience']=df['Experience'].str.replace(r'\D+','', regex=True).astype(int)
```

I get like

```
df.Experience.head(5)
```

```
0    24
1    12
2     9
3    12
4    20
Name: Experience, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

For the warning not to appear, just put `regex=True` inside the parentheses

EX: `str.replace('.', '',regex=True)`

Comment: Duplicate answer.