# Problem loading excel file and not showing the missing values and trying to use regex to clear and values in a cellphone number

Tags: python, excel, regex, dataframe

I have an Excel file with a lot of date from some customers.

For some reason when read the excel file, the jupyter notebook cannot visualize the field with missing values.
The reason for the missing values is because the customers didn't fufill this data.

I tried a lot of thing when exporting the data.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'Recomeco/Decisões 06.09 a 12.09.xlsx', index_col=0, skiprows=2)#, na_values=['CELULAR', 'EMAIL']) #keep_default_na = False, na_filter= False, verbose= True)
```

[image]

I dont know whats is the reason for this heappen.

In the CELULAR colum:

```
Cellphone_original     Cellphone_GOAL
(12)98272-8620          55 12 98272-8620
```

I used this function:

```
def split_CELULAR(celular):
    number = re.findall(r"\d+-\d+", celular)
    return number

df['CELULAR1'] = df['CELULAR'].apply(split_CELULAR)

Value find: 98272-8620
```

But I have to add the values - 55 12, to every row and I can't do it.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['CELULAR1'] = df['CELULAR'].str.replace(r'^\(\d+\)', '55 12 ', regex=True)
```

The regex (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLB3cE/1)) means:

- `^` - start of string
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
  -`\)` - a `)` char.

Note the `regex = True` argument, it is necessary to avoid warnings, see the [FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66603854/3832970) thread.