# I have a string "user@domain+12223334444" and I want to replace "+1" with space. How can I achieve it with str.replace command?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This string is in a column of dataframe. After running the below code, I am getting an error

```
patients_test["contact"] = patients_test["contact"].str.replace("+1", " ")
```

> Error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Comment: Is that a real persons name and email in the question title? If so it would be courteous to change them to a made up string that follows the same pattern.

Comment: Please remove all personal information, in particular from the title.

Comment: If this is parsed as a regex, a `+` at the beginning of the string is invalid, because `+` modifies the character before it to mean "one-or-more of that thing". You need to use `[+]` or otherwise escape it.

Comment: BTW, note that `+1` is not universal as a prefix -- it's used in the United States and Canada, yes, but if your dataset expands to other parts of the world you'll have other country codes.

Comment: @Ashish I want to impress something upon you that others have been gentle in saying: you are dealing with something called a "patient". By posting this information online, you may have just violated HIPPA, or other privacy legislation where you live, or where your customer does business. You should tell your employer/PI this has happened. Above all, *be careful and do not ever do that again.*

Comment: That information is part of an already [publicly accessible dataset](https://github.com/BaekKyunShin/Data-Analyst-Nanodegree/blob/master/Project4-Treatment_test/patients.csv) used for learning data analysis. This is not its first exposure on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `+` into `[+]` so it's a character class matching the character `+`, not  a modifier to make the previous thing be repeated one-or-more times.

```
patients_test["contact"] = patients_test["contact"].str.replace("[+]1", " ")
```

You could also use `"\\+1"` or `r"\+1"`, but I strongly advise the `[+]` approach as it works the same way no matter what kind of quoting context is being used.

Comment: If you want to avoid the [FutureWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66603854/15497888) you'll need to set the regex parameter: `.str.replace("[+]1", " ", regex=True)`

Comment: @HenryEcker, do you have any notes on from which version that warning is present? The docs say `regex` is valid starting in pandas 0.23, but that's all I've been able to find.

Comment: Version 1.2.0 - current release (1.3.5). It's in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66607872/15497888) to the linked question in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas str.replace does a regular expression match / replace by default.

That complexity is not necessary here, use

```
patients_test["contact"] = patients_test["contact"].str.replace("+1", " ", regex=False)
```

To use exact text matching without using a regular expression.