# Regex to remove dots only after short words and not after long words

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to remove dots from abbreviations in a Pandas dataframe but not if the dots are in between longer words. So 'l.t.d.' and 'ltd.' should result in 'ltd' but 'longword.' should remain the same.

The regex I now have is `(?:\b\w{1,3})(\.)`. From this regex, I want to replace the result in group 1 by an empty string. How can I tell `str.replace(r'(?:\b\w{1,3})(\.)', '')` to consider only the second group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\b([a-zA-Z]{1,3})\.', r'\1', regex=True)
## Or, to account for any Unicode letters:
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\b([^\W\d_]{1,3})\.', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SyGyhz/3). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([^\W\d_]{1,3})` - Group 1 (`\1`): one, two or three letters
- `\.` - a dot.

The `\1` in the replacement refers to the Group 1 value.

Note you should provide the `regex=True` argument to `Series.str.replace` to avoid the warning described in [FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66603854/3832970).