# Python Pandas: change default value to regex=true

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I always use regex to do any matching and replacement on Pandas columns.

Is it possible to set the default value for all `Series.str.replace`, `Series.str.contains`, etc to be `regex=True` in order to avoid `FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [common warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66603854/3832970) and you can get rid of it by defining your own `rereplace` function instead of [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) in the following way:

```py
pd.Series.str.rereplace = lambda self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0: self.replace(pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex=True)
```

You can customize `pandas.Series.str.contains`, too:

```py
pd.Series.str.recontains = lambda self, pat, case=True, flags=0, na=None: self.contains(pat, case, flags, na, regex=True)
```

Then, you will be able to run it using `df['col'].str.rereplace(pattern, replacement)`.

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series.str.rereplace = lambda self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0: self.replace(pat, repl, n, case,flags, regex=True)

df=pd.DataFrame({'col': ['12 pts']})
df['col'].str.rereplace(r'\d+', 'XXX')
```

Output:

```py
>>> df['col'].str.rereplace(r'\d+', 'XXX')
0    XXX pts
Name: col, dtype: object

>>> df['col'].str.recontains(r'ptS', case=True)
0    False
```